# How to read lsusb?

Tags: usb, utilities, usb-device

What is the vendor id and what is the product id in the output of `lsusb`?

```
➜ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 0781:5576 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0e0f:000b VMware, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 022: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 002 Device 019: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

In particular, I'm looking at "Future Technology Devices": `0403:6001`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "If it quacks like a keyboard and types like a keyboard it must be a
>   keyboard."

That's not always true. The `lsusb` utillity takes his information from a file called `/var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids` to look up the vendor ids, product ids, classes, subclasses and protocols. But, notice an USB device can imitate a wrong id (See [Rubber Ducky](http://hakshop.myshopify.com/products/usb-rubber-ducky-deluxe?variant=353378649) for example).

However, I like the `-t` option for further information about plugged devices. A USB-mouse would, for example, look like this:

```
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
```

The interessting part in the `Driver=usbhid`, where you can find out which driver the kernel uses for that specific device. The class of the device is HID, which means a [human interface device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device). In that case the plain `lsusb` entry would look like:

```
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c050 Logitech, Inc. RX 250 Optical Mouse
```

`046d` is the vendor id looked up as `Logitech, Inc.` and `c050` is the product id looked up as `RX 250 Optical Mouse`.

You can `grep` the id-file for those ids to check:

```
$ grep -P "^046d|c050" /var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids
046d  Logitech, Inc.
        c050  RX 250 Optical Mouse
```

Comment: Location of `usb.ids` may vary (on my system it's under `/usr/share/hwdata` and under `/usr/share/libosinfo/db`)

Answer (score 1):

The vendor id comes first (most general), then the product id.  Note that these values are in hex.

Another way to find out is that one of them should be listed as a vendor id here: http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids.